# Is there some issue with big string inside array elements?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to know if I can store a html page inside a array element? is there some performance problems with it? This page not will be so big but it can be a bit big.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, assuming you mean the HTML for the web page and not any objects (i.e. images, video) you can store an entire web page in an array element. You shouldn't have any issues with it unless it is an extraordinarily large web page.

Answer (score 1):

You can store as much as you want assuming it doesn't exceed `ini_get('memory_limit')`.